# Unexpected token JSON after I insert img tag

Tags: php, html, image

I'm trying to insert an image pixel in my php file `register.php`. The `img` tag acts as a tracking code where everytime a user registers, tracking code will send data to a website. Now its firing an alert `Unexpected token JSON` and registration is not working. Is there anyone that can help me, I just need to put the tracking code correctly but I don't know how.

```
function post_register($field) {
    $captcha;
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }

        $secretKey = "xxxx";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
          echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
        } else {
          global $wpdb;

    $first_name            = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name             = $_POST['last_name'];
    $business_number       = $_POST['business_number'];
    $email                 = $_POST['email'];   
    $password              = $_POST['register_password'];
    $password_confirmation = $_POST['password_confirmation'];
    $gbv_website           = $_POST['gbv_website'];
    $hear_about_us         = $_POST['hear_about_us'];
    $hasError              = false;
    $user_id               = '';
    /*$howto = $_POST['howto'];
    $callTransfer = $_POST['callTransfer'];*/

    if(trim($first_name) === '') {

        $error    = 'Please enter your first name.';
        $hasError = true;

    }elseif(trim($last_name) === '') {

        $error    = 'Please enter your last name.';
        $hasError = true;

    }elseif(trim($business_number) === '') {

        $error    = 'Please enter your business number.';
        $hasError = true;

    }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)  ) {

        $error     = 'Please enter a valid email.';
        $hasError = true;

    }elseif($password === '') {

        $error    = 'Please enter your password';
        $hasError = true;

    }elseif($password !== $password_confirmation){

        $error    = 'Password verification did not matched!';
        $hasError = true;

    }elseif(trim($gbv_website) === '') {

        $error    = 'Please enter your Website.';
        $hasError = true;

    }elseif(trim($hear_about_us) === '') {

        $error    = 'Please select one.';
        $hasError = true;

    }elseif(email_exists($email)){

        $error    = 'Email address already exists';
        $hasError = true;

    }
    /*elseif(trim($howto) === ''){
        $error    = 'Please select if Message Only or Call Screening & Transfer';
        $hasError = true;
    }*/
    else{

        // create user
        $user_id = wp_insert_user(['user_login' => $email, 'user_pass' => $password, 'user_email' => $email, 'first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name]);
    // echo '<img src="https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=90.00&tracking=1&transtype=sale&merchantID=49748" width="1" height="1">';


        if(is_wp_error($user_id)){

            $error    = $user_id->get_error_message();
            $hasError = true;

        }

    }

    if ($user_id > 0){
        //create user profile
        $profile_inserted = post_create_profile($user_id, $first_name, $last_name, $hear_about_us, $business_number, $email,  $howto, $callTransfer);

        if(!$profile_inserted){

            wp_delete_user($user_id);

            $error    = 'System encountered problem while creating your profile, please try again';
            $hasError = true;

        }else{

            //create user answer
            $answer_inserted = post_create_answer($user_id, $gbv_website);

            if(!$answer_inserted){

                wp_delete_user($user_id);

                $error    = 'System encountered problem while creating your answer, please try again';
                $hasError = true;

            }
        }
    }
    if($hasError) wp_redirect('/sign-up?error=' . urlencode($error));

    return $user_id;

    }


}
/*
    END OF REGISTRATION
    -------------------
    CREATE PROFILE
*/

function post_create_profile($user_id, $first_name, $last_name, $hear_about_us, $business_number, $email, $howTo, $callTransfer){

    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->insert(
                         $wpdb->prefix .'user_profile', 
                         [
                          'user_id'    => $user_id,
                          'full_name'  => $first_name .' '. $last_name,
                          'hear_about_us'   => $hear_about_us,
                          'business_number' => serialize(['business_number' => $business_number]),
                          'email_id'   => $email,
                          'ip_address' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                          'status'     => 6, //new register
                          'add_date'   => date('Y-m-d, H:i:s'),
                          'how_to'    => $howTo,
                          'call_transfer'    => $callTransfer,

                         ]);

}
/*
    END CREATE PROFILE
    ------------------
    CREATE ANSWER
*/
function post_create_answer($user_id, $gbv_website){

    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix .'user_answer', ['user_id' => $user_id, 'website' => $gbv_website, 'add_date' => date('Y-m-d, H:i:s')]);

}
/*
    END CREATE ANSWER
    ------------------
    SUBSCRIPTION
*/
function post_subscribe($provisioning){

    global $wpdb;

    $user            = get_userdata($provisioning->user_id);
    $subscription_id = elegant_id($provisioning->user_id);
    $phone_num       = unserialize($provisioning->phone_num);
    $address         = unserialize($provisioning->address);

    try{

        $result = ChargeBee_Subscription::create(array(
                                                    'id'             => $subscription_id,
                                                    'planId'         => 'popular-plan',
                                                    'customer'       => [
                                                                         'id'        => $subscription_id,
                                                                         'email'     => $user->user_email,
                                                                         'firstName' => $user->first_name,
                                                                         'lastName'  => $user->last_name,
                                                                         'company'   => $provisioning->company_name,
                                                                         'phone'     => $phone_num['phone_number']
                                                                        ],
                                                    'billingAddress' => [
                                                                         'firstName' => $user->first_name,
                                                                         'lastName'  => $user->last_name,
                                                                         'email'     => $provisioning->email_id,
                                                                         'company'   => $provisioning->company_name,
                                                                         'phone'     => $phone_num['phone_number'],
                                                                         'line1'     => $address['address1'],
                                                                         'line2'     => $address['address2'],
                                                                         'city'      => $provisioning->city,
                                                                         'state'     => $provisioning->state,
                                                                    //   'zip'       => $provisioning->zip,
                                                                         'country'   => 'US',
                                                                        ]

                                                ));

        $wpdb->update(
                      $wpdb->prefix .'user_answer',
                      [
                       'chargebee_customer_id'     => $subscription_id,
                       'chargebee_subscription_id' => $subscription_id,
                      ],
                      ['id' => $provisioning->user_answer_id]);

        $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix .'user_profile', ['status' => 2], ['id' => $provisioning->user_profile_id]);

        return ['result' => 'success', 'result' => $result->subscription()];

    }catch(Exception $e){

        return ['result' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()];

    }

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_check_user_email', 'check_user_email_callback' );
function check_user_email_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
    if(email_exists($_POST['email'])){
        echo json_encode('Email address already used.');
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode('true');
    }
    die();
}

    echo '<img src="https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=59.00&tracking=12345&transtype=sale&merchantID=xxxxx" width="1" height="1">';
```

Comment: Is `6LccSg0UAAAAAHsb2AGKEaloWQowH5stYxoRnlhR` your secret key?

Comment: You echo out the JSON data then you echo the `IMG` tag - the img tag will break the JSON, hence the error

Comment: @RamRaider the code is at the bottom
<img src="https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=59.00&tracking=12345&transtype=sale&merchantID=xxxxx" width="1" height="1">

Comment: @rap-2-h yes it is

Comment: You should keep it secret. I will edit your question and change it by `xxxx`

Comment: @rap-2-h thanks, the real issue here is I need to insert the `img` tag.

Comment: Sorry but you can't insert HTML tracking code in the middle of a JSON response, just like you can't insert it in the middle of a PDF document or a video stream. Not everything in life is HTML!

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález how can I insert the html tag? thanks I didn't know about that

Comment: You can return a JSON object that contains both a status message and the image tag in different properties. Then the client can use `response.status` to get the message, and `response.image` to get the image tag.